# How do I allow a selection to be made in each listbox in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been struggling with a homework assignment and to get the desired layout and functionality. I am unable to achieve my goal of having a highlighted selection in each listbox. I am not sure if it is something wrong with how I wrote the program and if I need to rewrite it, or a simple fix I need to make, any help appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from Clock import Clock

class Clock(Clock):
    def __init__(self):
        self.seconds = 0
        self.minutes = 0
        self.hours = 0
        self.days = 1
        self.month = 1
        self.year = 1980
    def increase_second(self):
        return super().increase_second()
    def decrease_second(self):
        return super().decrease_second()
    def increase_day(self):
        return super().increase_day()
    def decrease_day(self):
        return super().decrease_day()
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()
    

clock_instance = Clock()


def set_clock():
    selected_seconds = seconds_listbox.get(seconds_listbox.curselection())
    selected_minutes = minutes_listbox.get(minutes_listbox.curselection())
    selected_hours = hours_listbox.get(hours_listbox.curselection())
    selected_days = days_listbox.get(days_listbox.curselection())
    selected_months = months_listbox.get(months_listbox.curselection())
    selected_year = year_listbox.get(year_listbox.curselection())

    clock_instance.seconds = int(selected_seconds)
    clock_instance.minutes = int(selected_minutes)
    clock_instance.hours = int(selected_hours)
    clock_instance.days = int(selected_days)
    clock_instance.month = int(selected_months) + 1
    clock_instance.year = int(selected_year)

    update_label_text()


def update_label_text():
    output_label.config(text=str(clock_instance))

def quit_gui():
    window.quit()

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Clock GUI")

window.geometry("700x550")

# Frames
top_frame = tk.Frame(window)
top_frame.pack()

middle_frame = tk.Frame(window)
middle_frame.pack()

bottom_frame = tk.Frame(window)
bottom_frame.pack()

# Labels top frame
label1 = tk.Label(top_frame, text="Clock Output:")
label1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
output_label = tk.Label(top_frame, text="Current Time")
output_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
update_label_text()

# Listboxes middle frame
seconds_label = tk.Label(middle_frame, text="Seconds")
seconds_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
seconds_listbox = tk.Listbox(middle_frame, width=10, selectmode="browse")
for i in range(60):
    seconds_listbox.insert(tk.END, i)
seconds_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

minutes_label = tk.Label(middle_frame, text="Minutes")
minutes_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
minutes_listbox = tk.Listbox(middle_frame, width=10, selectmode="browse")
for i in range(60):
    minutes_listbox.insert(tk.END, i)
minutes_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

hours_label = tk.Label(middle_frame, text="Hours")
hours_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
hours_listbox = tk.Listbox(middle_frame, width=10, selectmode="browse")
for i in range(24):
    hours_listbox.insert(tk.END, i)
hours_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

days_label = tk.Label(middle_frame, text="Day")
days_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
days_listbox = tk.Listbox(middle_frame, width=10, selectmode="browse")
for i in range(1, 32):
    days_listbox.insert(tk.END, i)
days_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

month_list = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
months_label = tk.Label(middle_frame, text="Month")
months_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
months_listbox = tk.Listbox(middle_frame, selectmode="browse")
for month in month_list:
    months_listbox.insert(tk.END, month)
months_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

year_label = tk.Label(middle_frame, text="Years")
year_label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
year_listbox = tk.Listbox(middle_frame, width=10, )
for i in range(1900, 2101):
    year_listbox.insert(tk.END, i)
year_listbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)


# Buttonsbottom frame
set_time_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Set Time", command=set_clock)
set_time_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

increase_day_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Increase Day", command=clock_instance.increase_day)
increase_day_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

decrease_day_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Decrease Day", command=clock_instance.decrease_day)
decrease_day_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

Increase_second_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Increase Second", command=clock_instance.increase_second)
Increase_second_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

decrease_second_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Decrease Second", command=clock_instance.decrease_second)
decrease_second_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

quit_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Quit", command=quit_gui)
quit_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Here is what I want to recreate, does not have to be 1:1.[[image]]

Comment: You need to add `exportselection=0` when creating those `Listbox` widgets.